# how to override sitecore.context.database.getitem(string path) in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I want to pick up an item of **en** language for any language. whenever I call `Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID)` the item should be fetched of **en** language even if the context language is *fr-fr*.

I'm trying to use fallback language option but as per the requirement, fallback language may not be **en** it can change as per need. Is there a way i can write a pipeline to override this function.

I do not want to use language fallback as the target language can be any language.

Comment: I think you **should** be using fallback to handle this as the simplest solution. Language Fallback is chained, you so can make `en` the last in that chain, and then don't create any other language versions of those items you only want in English. Doing this in code you will find lots of edges case you have not thought of. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

The GetItem method has an overload method as follows:

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(sitecoreIdhere, language here);
```

So, you can make use of this overload method and pass the language `en` as parameters as follows:

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID, Language.Parse("en"));
```

Or

```
Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("ItemPathHere", Language.Parse("en"));
```

**UPDATE**

It is not possible to override the method GetItem because there is no pipelines or processors which have the namespace `Sitecore.Data`

Comment: I know, we have this method. I have a scenario where I want to override the first method instead of using the two parameter method overload method using pipeline if possible. Just want to know if this is possible or not.

Comment: You may try to add it to the processor <getItem> but not sure if you can override the getitem